# Are summoned monsters edible and nourishing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I just read through [summon minor monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-minor-monster)
and I wondered: if a dragon or lizardlike creature had sorcerer levels and could cast those, could it use that to summon creatures for the purpose of hunting those down and eating them?

Comment: Why a reptilian caster specifically?

Comment: because a dragon player had asked me and repitilians are predestined to eat small animals^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

When you kill a summoned creature it returns to its original plane.  You can't eat something without killing it.  This rule applies to all conjuration school, summoning sub-school spells:

> Summoning: a summoning spell instantly brings a creature or object to
>   a place you designate. When the spell ends or is dispelled, a summoned
>   creature is instantly sent back to where it came from, but a summoned
>   object is not sent back unless the spell description specifically
>   indicates this. A summoned creature also goes away if it is killed or
>   if its hit points drop to 0 or lower, but it is not really dead. It
>   takes 24 hours for the creature to reform, during which time it can't
>   be summoned again.

Comment: Normally yes, but in this case I'm unsure as they are animals that are summoned there.  Sure that these are also counting as "extraplanar"?

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes.  All spells of the summoning sub-school behave this way.  See my edit.

Comment: You can totally eat something without killing it - by draining some of its blood to drink or amputating a limb.

Comment: @SPavel If you're draining it's blood or cutting off a limb, you're reducing it's HP.  The spell summons "1d3 Tiny or smaller animals, such as bats, lizards, monkeys, rats, ravens, toads, or weasels."  None of those creatures have more than a handful of HP.

Comment: @LegendaryDude As far as I am aware, the game does not give fewer HP to amputees, nor is recovering HP linked to regrowing limbs. Do you have citations to the contrary?

Comment: @SPavel How can you cut off a limb from a creature without harming it?  A creature with 4 HP is not going to survive that trauma.

Comment: How much HP does a commoner have? Does every commoner die after losing a limb?

Comment: @SPavel There are no rules in Pathfinder for dismemberment.  An attack against a 4HP creature will almost certainly kill it outright, not simply remove it's limb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37779/discussion-between-spavel-and-legendarydude).

Comment: @SPavel Extraplanar dairy cows, perhaps?

Comment: You could follow it to its plane and kill it there I guess.